# webpack-internal:///2:129 ag-grid: invalid gridOptions property '__ob__' did you mean any of these:

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

Noticed this new error in the console:

```
webpack-internal:///2:129 ag-grid: invalid gridOptions property '__ob__' did you mean any of these: groupSuppressBlankHeader,slaveGrids,rowData,columnDefs,excelStyles,pinnedTopRowData,pinnedBottomRowData,components
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///2:129
```

Couldn't figure it out, eventually decided to run the official Ag-Grid Vue example from:

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-vue-example

and it has the same type of errors:

```
webpack-internal:///2:129 ag-grid: invalid gridOptions property '__ob__' did you mean any of these: groupSuppressBlankHeader,slaveGrids,rowData,columnDefs,excelStyles,pinnedTopRowData,pinnedBottomRowData,components
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///2:129
webpack-internal:///2:132 ag-grid: to see all the valid gridOptions properties please check: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/
GridOptionsWrapper.checkProperties @ webpack-internal:///2:132
webpack-internal:///2:129 ag-grid: invalid colDef property '__ob__' did you mean any of these: rowGroupIndex,children,allowedAggFuncs,menuTabs,pivotTotalColumnIds,cellClassRules,icons,headerGroupComponent
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///2:129
webpack-internal:///2:132 ag-grid: to see all the valid colDef properties please check: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/
GridOptionsWrapper.checkProperties @ webpack-internal:///2:132
webpack-internal:///2:129 ag-grid: invalid colDef property '__ob__' did you mean any of these: rowGroupIndex,children,allowedAggFuncs,menuTabs,pivotTotalColumnIds,cellClassRules,icons,headerGroupComponent
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///2:129
webpack-internal:///2:132 ag-grid: to see all the valid colDef properties please check: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/
GridOptionsWrapper.checkProperties @ webpack-internal:///2:132
webpack-internal:///2:129 ag-grid: invalid colDef property '__ob__' did you mean any of these: rowGroupIndex,children,allowedAggFuncs,menuTabs,pivotTotalColumnIds,cellClassRules,icons,headerGroupComponent
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///2:129
webpack-internal:///2:132 ag-grid: to see all the valid colDef properties please check: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/
GridOptionsWrapper.checkProperties @ webpack-internal:///2:132
webpack-internal:///2:129 ag-grid: invalid colDef property '__ob__' did you mean any of these: rowGroupIndex,children,allowedAggFuncs,menuTabs,pivotTotalColumnIds,cellClassRules,icons,headerGroupComponent
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///2:129
webpack-internal:///2:132 ag-grid: to see all the valid colDef properties please check: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/
```

These are all in the official example repo!
Suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're passing reactive properties to `gridOptions`. Use
[Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) or [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) with `writable` false to create the options.

**edit**

I was able to fix the warnings using:

```
// gridOptions.ts
let options: GridOptions = {}

Object.defineProperty(options, 'enableFilter', {
  enumerable: true,
  value: true,
  writable: false
})

....

export default options
```

**edit**

Another thing, and this is by no means a *good* idea, but editing the `checkProperties` function in the `gridOptionsWrapper` class you can filter on the invalid property keys to remove `__ob__`:

```
// line 126
var invalidPropertyKeys = Object.keys(invalidProperties).filter(key => key !== '__ob__');
```

Comment: thanks, makes sense, also seeing that issue in rowData 
pretty sure this was working with reactive properties before I refactored the code to use vuex-class.

Comment: didn't have much luck with that, tried lodash deepclone too.
Here is a repo showing the `__ob__` issue if anyone has suggestions.

There is a second issue, not reproducible in that repo yet, in which the injected Vuex state disappears, will try to reproduce that.

https://github.com/davidmoshal/poi-ts-vue-jest-example

Comment: Dang, I hoped that would have worked for you, I've included what I did yesterday to create the options just in case. The warnings about `__ob__` went away with that change.